# What does "Still Running" mean (Linux)?

Tags: linux, logging, reboot

```
$ last -x reboot
reboot system boot 4.4.0-46-generic Mon Nov 14 12:15 still running
```

What does the "`still running`" mean at the end of the log entry?

- Did the server reboot?
- Is it going try later?
- Is it still rebooting, or is something else still running and it's waiting?

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find any reference to this.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page

> The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted.  Thus last reboot will show a log of all the reboots since the log file was created.

The reboot user hasn't logged out since you've rebooted, this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the OS has not been rebooted since Mon Nov 14.

`last` searches the file `/var/log/wtmp` to show who logged in and out.  The user `reboot` logs run level changes (like reboot of the machine) which is shown by `last -x`.  I found this from `man reboot`.

What OS are you running?  On my Lubuntu 14.04 it does not show "still running" for reboot.   This looks specific to OS implementation.

It *does* show "still logged in" for each of the terminal sessions my user account **vagrant** has open, which is what I expect to see.

```
vagrant@cordelia:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l

vagrant@cordelia:~$ last -x reboot | grep -i still
vagrant@cordelia:~$ last -x reboot 
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-77-generi Tue Sep 13 11:47 - 08:26 (63+21:39)  
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-77-generi Mon Sep 12 12:21 - 16:23  (04:02)    

wtmp begins Fri Sep  9 11:23:08 2016
vagrant@cordelia:~$ 


vagrant@cordelia:~$ last | grep -i still | head
vagrant  pts/4        :0               Wed Nov 16 08:22   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/18       :0               Wed Nov  2 10:25   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/17       :0               Wed Oct 19 10:23   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/16       :0               Fri Sep 16 09:36   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/15       :0               Fri Sep 16 09:30   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/13       :0               Fri Sep 16 09:22   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/12       :0               Wed Sep 14 14:52   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/10       :0               Wed Sep 14 14:35   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/9        :0               Wed Sep 14 14:34   still logged in   
vagrant  pts/5        :0               Tue Sep 13 15:28   still logged in   
vagrant@cordelia:~$
```

Comment: _"On my Lubuntu 14.04 it does not show "still running" for reboot. "_ I suspect it's kernel-version dependent. I see in your `last -x` output that you're running a 3.13.0 kernel, while the OP is running 4.4.0. Checking on my own (Debian) systems, I get the "still running" on those running 4.x and 5.x kernels, but not 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

`still running` means the server is still running since the last reboot shown in the timestamps.

So to answer your question:

Did the server reboot? yes
Is it going try later? not really
Is it still rebooting? no

Also note that `still running` can show up on several records in the case there was an unintentional shutdown (due to power loss, for example), which was not recognized as `shutdown` by the system.